# Invalid OCSP signing certificate in OCSP response

Tags: tls, chrome, firefox, ocsp

I want to open the following page in Firefox, and get an error.

https://www.acm.nl/nl/

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to www.acm.nl. 
Invalid OCSP signing certificate in OCSP response. 
(Error code: sec_error_ocsp_invalid_signing_cert)

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity 
of the received data could not be verified.
```

When I open this page in Chrome it opens normally. Why does Firefox object?

Comment: Have you trusted the CA that is signing the OCSP responses? It is often a different CA than signs the certificates themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems their OCSP-cert has expired on September 10th.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 132 (0x84)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=NL, O=Digidentity B.V., CN=Digidentity Services CA - G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 20 10:40:55 2012 GMT
            Not After : Sep 10 10:40:55 2014 GMT
        Subject: C=NL, O=Digidentity B.V., CN=Digidentity OCSP
```

**Code**
I used these three commands:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.acm.nl:443 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > acm.pem

$ openssl s_client -connect www.acm.nl:443 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null > chain.pembundle

$ openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pembundle -cert acm.pem -url $(openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in acm.pem)
Response Verify Failure
2676036:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:126:Verify error:certificate has expired
acm.pem: ERROR: No Status found.
```

**More Detail**
Use this instead of third command for more detail:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer chain.pembundle -cert acm.pem -text -url $(openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in acm.pem)
```

**Link**
I copied the commands from here: https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_Manually_Verify_a_certificate_against_an_OCSP.html

Comment: Very interesting. I thought it was a browser specific issue, as another Firefox browser did show the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> When I open this page in Chrome it opens normally. Why does Firefox object?

Chrome only does very limited checking of revocations, especially it does not use OCSP any longer. Firefox instead does OCSP checks.

Comment: I just tried Firefox on another computer, and there it worked. So maybe it was an addon? I installed all relevant addons installed in this browser, and still it works. Any ideas what might cause this, or should I clean up Firefox?

Comment: try setting security.OCSP.require to true in about:config, I am replicating it that way

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your system date is incorrect. If it's in the past or future, the certificate would be invalid.